# Problems importing Dolibarr 6 database to Dolibarr 12

Tags: crm, dolibarr

We have two Dolibarr in operation in two different domains. One of them has a version 6.0 and another with a clean installation 12.0.

Performing the installation I was able to bring all the content to version 12 from an export-import of the database.

The point is that we are still working with version 6.0 and I want to migrate the Agenda and Third Party events that are taking place day after day to fill in and nurture the CRM. Logically, if I import all the content from CRM 6 to 12, the Dolibarr installation forces me to reinstall and reconfigure everything.

https://www.dolibarr.org/forum/uploads/dolibarrorg/original/2X/f/f82804018c7ccd1e3ef5c18a4c42d418953e19e3.png

But I don’t see that it can be Imported. No way.

Does anyone know any method that does not involve a mysqldump from the database?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you want go from v6 to v12, with no loss of data, you must install manually v7 over v6, v8 over v7, and so on till v12 over v11.
Then start working production in v12, and you will have all data up to date.

Regards
Eduardo.